# Disable Vim plugin for certain filetypes

Tags: vim, macvim

I'd like to disable a plugin for certain filetypes in Vim. I'm a Vim newbie, so take it slow with me :)

I have the autocomplpop plugin, and I really like it. However, if I'm editing a LaTeX file, it shows completions for every single English language word I've already used. It's distracting! I'd like to disable it for .tex files, but I have no idea how to do so.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting this in your .vimrc after you enabled filetype plugins.

```
autocmd FileType tex :AcpDisable
```

This should disable the auto completion for tex files.

Comment: and for the rest of the plugins ? sytastic, vdebug, snipmate ...?
for instance disable vdebug plugin in python files  
 
autocmd FileType py :vdebugDisable  

would work? how it works?

Comment: @alfonsodev, it depends. Sometimes you could set a local variable, i.e `let someplugin_loaded=1` to disable the plugin. You could refer to the plugin you want to disable for further information.